# What's the meaning of the "row" class in Bootstrap, its difference from containers, and how does it stack with col-***-*?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row

I'm trying to follow the guide here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/
and I just can't seem to understand what the "row" class is doing. I was trying some of the examples in the guide such as:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

I tried it with the row `div` and without it, and I was trying to place everything inside a container, and there was no difference at all, they all looked the same.

Could anyone explain what the meaning of the "row" class is ?

Comment: Basically the difference is in margins and padding: see [for example](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/EVGvjw?editors=110). (Plus more difference for different types of containers... See [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Bootstrap, the "row" class is used mainly to hold columns in it. Bootstrap divides each row into a grid of 12 virtual columns. In the following example, the `col-md-6` div will have the width of 6/12 of the "row"s div, meaning 50%. The `col-md-4` will hold 33.3%, and the `col-md-2` will hold the remaining 16.66%.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what happens if you dont wrap those divs inside a row? i tried to run this example with and without the row wrapper, and i cant tell the difference.

Comment: Not exactly. All the "col-..." div are float left or right, so if they are higher than their parent element, they will "spill" out of it. Such case can generate overlapping of elements in the view. A simple fix for that, which "row" class does for you, is to make a "clearfix" which will make the parent generate height by it's children wether they float or not

Comment: I also noticed that the `row` class implements `margin-left: -15px; margin-right:-15px` I think it's related to some fix related to the fact the `col`s have `padding-left:15px; padding-right: 15px`

Answer (score 4):

I like to think of the row as a container that can contain X many columns equal to 12. You would use the row class to separate different stacked element (columns).

The columns as you defined them col-xs-12 col-md-8 mean that on a medium sized screen and above the div will span 8/12 of the page and on a xs small screen (mobile) it will span the full 12 columns. This works with the col-xs-12 col-md-4 class because 8 + 4 = 12.

If your entire site is split this way (8/12 and 4/12) then all you really would need is one row! Other wise you'd create another row for different column width. An example would be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The container class is used to create a nice margin around your entire site, but if you have a portion of your site you want to span across the entire width, you would need to close the container and create a container-fluid class. Then create another container to get the margin back. Hope that all makes since! Just how I think about it as.

Answer (score 0):

The difference can be seen here with row class. Row like container is a class applied to the element.

P.S: run the snippet in full view

```css
.color {
  background: #cfcfcf
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='color container'>
  Container only
</div>

<p>
  <div class='color container-fluid'>
    <div class=row>
      Fluid Container & row

    </div>
  </div>
  <p>

    <div class='color container'>
      <div class=row>
        Container & Row

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted your answer, but this answer is not very clear; all three containers look the same in your demo.

Comment: Thanks @TylerH. I guess I should have mentioned to run the code snippet in full view :)

Comment: I see the minor difference between the "Container only" and the "Container & row", but i cant point exacly what that difference is? all i can see is a small padding to the left?

Comment: @HayNHasida the container is padding 15 px on left and right. Adding the row class offsets the padding and brings the layout inline. this is particularly useful when doing complex layouts